# Save Form Data in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I’m currently working on a browser kind of app these days using `UIWebView`.

In this app, I want to save the form data, so whenever user visit the same page and 
try to fill data on the text field present in the same page, I want to provide **suggestions** or **Autocompletion** thing.
How can I achieve this, I’m not pretty sure but Android has something like `setSaveFormData` method in `WebView` to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('yourElementName').value='some-value';"];
```

to populate element `yourElementName` with `some-value`

Comment: I don't know what webpage user gonna visit with my app, how can I make sure the relevant data should come

Comment: @Stranger I believe that in such case you cant, you should know what you want to populate...

Comment: For example, user visits hotmail/yahoo mail and provided login details to login. once he done, he logged out. Now next time he visit the same page and start typing his email id, on very first character he type, I want to show all the suggestions start with the same letter (the way a normal desktop browser does).

Comment: @Stranger you can get all text fields in webview and populate them with some value, but you can't create universal solution that will work on all forms